# question about twisted group of Lie type A_n

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G=PSU_3(q)$ and $q=p^n$, where $n$ is odd. Can we conclude that $PSU_3(p)$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: By the way, you haven't reacted to my answer to your question yesterday about ${\rm PSU}_n(q)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $SU_3(q) \subset SU_3(q^2)$ is the subgroup of elements Galois-conjugate to their inverse. $SU_3(p)$ is the subgroup of elements defined over $p$ and Galois-conjugate to their inverse. Since the relevant Galois action is the same, they are the same. Then we mod out by the centers, which preserves inclusions.